# TinyMCE(v5.92): behave differently in firefox(v91) vs chrome (v93)

Tags: css, angular, tinymce

I have just upgraded my project with its dependencies to Angular 12. Among other dependencies, I also use the TinyMCE text editor npm package (not the TinyMCE Angular integration) as an inline editor and I have implemented a directive for it.

So far it works fine with Chrome. whenever I click/focus on textarea the TinyMCE editor pop-up on the top of the textarea as I expected but in Firefox it pop-up on top of the page which is not the right place. I'm very confused now why it appears properly in its own place in Chrome but not firefox? I'm expecting the same behavior as Chrome.

It would be very helpful if anyone helps me throughout the tricky bug?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I have the same problem. Firefox the inline options appear top left of screen rather then on top of the editor box. Chrome works perfectly